# What's the most efficient iron golem farm design for SMP?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

This takes into account size, materials required, and golems spawning and villager placement.

I'm aware that there's a design to spawn villagers and subsequently spawn iron golems when you reach around 12 villagers, but what's the most efficient design that utilizes the best of all of the above, yet is simply automated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Looking at Docm77 Design its really good:

Answer (score 2):

Since you ask for both materials and productivity, this will be difficult to answer. I mean: have a look at The Iron Trench.

Its iron production is totally over the top. Its material cost and complexity is quite impressive too. The tradeoff will always be between simple, cheap, less efficient and expensive, complex and more efficient. So, unless you come up with some formula how to determine the cost taking into account "size, materials required, and golems spawning and villager placement" (as the first two go simply against the third), this question is pretty much "non-constructive".

(personally, I found [Design by Trunkz](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Iron_golem_farming#Design_by_trunkz) to cover all my singleplayer needs in excess - probably like 4x excess. In your case it depends on how many players it would be serving. For some 4-5 this would be sufficient. For more, pick a more advanced design.)